# ¿Como sumar un valor JS con un Valor PHP e imprimir con un echo sin usar botón?

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un problema, espero me puedan apoyar, quiero sumar el valor js con uno php e imprimir

var variableJS = 5;

```
<script> 
    var variableJS = 5;   
</script>


<?php
$num = 3;
$resultado = $num+ <<< variableJS >>>   <---- Ejemplo
?>

  <!-- imprimir con php -->
<?php echo $resultado ?>
```

Comment: Envía el valor de la variable por $_POST['variable_js'], o recibe el valor desde PHP por $_GET['variable_js'], depende de las necesidades de tu proyecto. Lo que si te aclaro, es que no puedes hacerlo de esa manera, ya que son lenguajes completamente diferentes, el uno(JS) trabaja sobre el frontend y el otro (PHP) en el backend. Si explicas mejor lo que quieres hacer tal vez alguien pueda ayudarte,

Answer (score 0):

Esto que estás tratando de hacer no es posible.

En resumidas cuentas el motivo es que el código PHP se ejecuta antes y en diferentes procesos que el código JavaScript, por lo que desde PHP no puedes obtener el valor de una variable de JavaScript.

Eso sí, puedes hacer lo contrario, es decir desde JavaScript recibir el valor de una variable de PHP:

```
<?php
    $num = 3;
?>

<span id="resultado"></span>

<script> 
    var variableJS = 5;
    var variablePHP = <?php echo $num; ?>;
    document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = variableJS + variablePHP;   
</script>
```

El motivo de esto es que cuando haces una petición al servidor Web, lo que hace éste en primer lugar es interpretar tu código PHP y devolver como respuesta un fichero HTML que tu navegador es capaz de interpretar. En el ejemplo que te he puesto, el servidor web reemplazaría por ejemplo esto:

```
var variablePHP = <?php echo $num; ?>;
```

por esto:

```
var variablePHP = 3;
```

Llegado el punto en el que el navegador recibe el fichero HTML, donde el código PHP ha quedado reemplazado por código 100% HTML+JS, ya no hay manera de ejecutar más código PHP; y ahora el navegador lo que hace es empezar a ejecutar el código de JavaScript.

Fíjate que estos dos códigos los ejecutan procesos diferentes: PHP lo ejecuta el servidor web, y el código JavaScript lo ejecuta el cliente web o navegador. También se ejecutan en momentos diferentes, todo el código PHP se va a ejecutar antes de que se ejecute cualquier código JavaScript que haya en el fichero HTML que se haya generado.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tienes es que se ejecutan en diferentes tiempos de ejecución, me podrías dar un poco mas de información de lo que deseas realizar, para ver si te puedo ayudar?

saludos!

Comment: Eso es más un comentario que una respuesta, por favor lee [answer] y evita usar el area de respuestas para comentarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de que php es un lenguaje del lado del servidor y javascript es un lenguaje para el cliente. Una vez que tu código de Javascript se ejecuta php desde el servidor no cuenta con acceso para acceder a tus variables de js.
El camino correcto para comunicar ambos lenguajes es a partir de peticiones HTTP.

Dejando eso en claro, si tú variable de JS será una constante, y requieres de esta variable del lado del servidor, cómo es el caso del ejemplo, lo correcto es que declares dicha variable en tu código php.

También me gustaría agregar que existen “workarounds” para ejecutar código JS del lado del servidor, pero no son las mejores prácticas.